# cakephp-3 form validation for length range (between)

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I am converting Cakephp-1 project to Cakephp-3. So I need help to convert the validation code:

**Cakephp-1 Code**

```
'name' => array(
    'between' => array(
        'rule' => array('between', 2, 50),
        'message' => 'Ditt namn måste vara minst två tecken långt!'
     )
)
```

I have try the code:

**Cakephp-3 Code**

```
$validator
    ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('name')
    ->add('name', [
        'between' => [
            'rule' => [2, 50],
            'message' => 'Namnet måste vara mellan 2 och 50 tecken lång!',
        ]
    ]);
```

But it gives me the error:

> Unable to call method "2" in "default" provider for field "name"...

Now what can I do ??

Answer (score 2):

The correct code should be

```
->add('name', [
    [
       'rule' => ['lengthbetween', 2, 50],
       'message' => 'Namnet måste vara mellan 2 och 50 tecken lång!',
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set different validation messages for each minimum length and maximum length:

```
$validator
    ->add('body', [
        'minLength' => [
            'rule' => ['minLength', 10],
            'last' => true,
            'message' => 'Comments must have a substantial body.'
        ],
        'maxLength' => [
            'rule' => ['maxLength', 250],
            'message' => 'Comments cannot be too long.'
        ]
    ]);
```